# Automate NodeJS Express Get and Post request using Cron

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

I have an existing get and post request from database which is:

```
router.post('/stackExample', async (req, res) => {
  try {

    //MAKE GET REQUEST FROM MONGODB
    const stackCron = await Borrower.aggregate([
      { $unwind: { path: "$application", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
      {
        $project: {
          'branch': '$branch',
          'status': '$application.status',
        },
      },
      { $match: { status: 'Active' } },
    ]);      

//MAKE POST REQUEST TO MONGODB
    for (let k = 0; k < stackCron.length; k++) {
      const branch = stackCron[k].branch;
      const status = stackCron[k].status;    
      const lrInterest = await Financial.updateOne({ accountName: 'Processing Fee Income'},
        {
          $push:
          {
            "transactions":
            {
              type: 'Credit',
              firstName: 'SysGen',
              lastName: 'SysGen2',
              amount: 100,
              date: new Date(),
            }
          }
        })
    }    

    res.json({ success: true, message: "Success" });
     } catch (err) { res.json({ success: false, message: 'An error occured' }); }

  });
```

This code works fine if request is made using the client but I want to automate this via cron:

Here is what I did:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function () {

  makeRequest()

}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();



function makeRequest(message){
//Copy-paste entire router post request.    
}
```

There seems to be no response if I copy-paste my code in the function. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no response from a `cron` job because there is no `request` coming to your `makeRequest` function. That makes sense because a `cron` job is independent of any incoming requests.
2. One other reason, you might not be getting any data from your `updateOne` operation is that it doesn't return the updated document. It returns the status of that operation instead. Take a look [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-updateOne). If you want to get the updated document you might want to use `findOneAndUpdate`.

```js
const response = await Todo.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "a1s2d3f4f4d3s2a1s2d3f4" },
  { title: "Get Groceries" },
  { new: true }
);
// response will have updated document
// We won't need this here. This is just to tell you how to get the updated document without making another database query explicitly
```

3. The body of your router function is performing an `async/await` operation. But you didn't specify the `makeRequest` function to be `async`. This could also be the issue.
4. `cron` job will update the database but if you want to get the updated documents, you'll have to make a `GET` call to the server and define a new route, with required parameters/query.

Your `makeRequest` function will look something like this

```js
async function makeRequest() {
  try {
    //MAKE GET REQUEST FROM MONGODB
    const stackCron = await Borrower.aggregate([
      { $unwind: { path: "$application", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
      {
        $project: {
          branch: "$branch",
          status: "$application.status",
        },
      },
      { $match: { status: "Active" } },
    ]);

    //MAKE POST REQUEST TO MONGODB
    for (let k = 0; k < stackCron.length; k++) {
      const branch = stackCron[k].branch;
      const status = stackCron[k].status;
      const lrInterest = await Financial.updateOne(
        { accountName: "Processing Fee Income" },
        {
          $push: {
            transactions: {
              type: "Credit",
              firstName: "SysGen",
              lastName: "SysGen2",
              amount: 100,
              date: new Date(),
            },
          },
        }
      );
    }
    /**
     * Write to a log file if you want to keep the record of this operation
     */
  } catch (err) {
    /**
     * Similarly write the error to the same log file as well.
     */
  }
}
```

In your `cron` job

```js
var job = new CronJob(
  "* * * * * *",
  async function () {
    await makeRequest();
  },
  null,
  true,
  "America/Los_Angeles"
);
```

Your new route

```js
router.get("/stack/:accountName", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { accountName } = req.params;
  try {
    const financial = await Financial.find({ accountName });
    res.status(200).json({ message: "success", data: financial });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "error", reason: err.message });
  }
});
```

Simply call it as

```
fetch(
  `http://example.net/stack/${encodeURIComponent("Processing Fee Income")}`,
  { method: "GET" }
);
```